# subfolders in iPhone localization folders

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I would like to localize some images in my iPhone project. So I created files:

```
en.lproj/Images/iPad/btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
en.lproj/Images/iPadRetina/btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
ru.lproj/Images/iPad/btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
ru.lproj/Images/iPadRetina/btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
```

and so on and added them to my project. But Xcode shows "English 0 files localized", "Russian 0 files localized" in Localizations list.

It also shows a warning

`Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestLocalizationDefaultPNG-ckplzmcjurofxrccjuvyzjaqketc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestLocalizationDefaultPNG.app/btn-check-pressed~ipad.png`

for each of my files when I try to build the project. So, as far as I understand, it copies all files in one folder, and since my files have the same names - only one of them can survive. But, if I remove my subfolders:

```
en.lproj/btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
en.lproj/btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
ru.lproj/btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
ru.lproj/btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
```

everything works fine.

Is there is a way to keep subfolders? Here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html in Listing 2-4 subfolder used for the audio files, so it should be.

Comment: try clearing your derived data and build it. Derived data tends to get naughty often, especially when there are changes made on to the lproj files.  let me know if that helps

Comment: Product->Clean? It doesn't help.

Comment: goto organizer (on your XCode, top right corner button), select the Projects tab on top, and then on the left bar, select the current open project. On the right side section, you can see an option to delete the derived data. Product-->Clean doesn't clear derived data

Comment: I see. Doesn't help either. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only way localization works in iOS is different. You base folders hierarchy should be by inverted: first goes actual folders structure and in each and every folder you want to localize, you put corresponding `.lproj` sub-folder with localized resources. So in your example it should be something like:

```
/Images
 /iPad
  /en.lproj
    btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
  /ru.lproj
    btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
 /iPadRetina
  /en.lproj
    btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
  /ru.lproj
    btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
```

This might be sub-optimal if you intended to have big hierarchy but this is the only way it works out of the box.

Of course you can always say that you don't need Xcode support and use some custom build rules to re-arrange files in you project in the way you like and then copy them into proper structure during build but I doubt it worths troubles.

**Update**: it looks like XCode (*4.5*) build script is the main villain.

According to my experiments build script should flattens resources structure at least for images. So the only way localized app can be inside is:

```
/YourApp
 YouApp
 info.plist
 ....
 /en.lproj
   btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
   btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
 /ru.lproj
   btn-check-pressed~ipad.png
   btn-check-pressed@2x~ipad.png
```

The trick is that by default XCode (as of version 4.5) can flatten your project structure only if it is as described above and I don't see a standard way to change this behavior.

Of course, original comment about custom build scripts is still true.